# Apache2 host two sites on the same server

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu

I am trying to host subversion and wiki on the same site.

I have created two files in /etc/apache2/sites-available

in "subversion"

I have

```
<VirtualHost -myserverIP-:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName  svn.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/svn/repos
        <Location /svn/repos>
                DAV svn
                SVNPath /var/svn/repos
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Subversion Repository"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
      Require valid-user
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

and in "wiki" I have

```
<VirtualHost -myserverIP-:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName wiki
        ServerAlias -myserverIP-

        DocumentRoot /home/www/wiki/html
        <Directory /home/www/wiki/html>
                AllowOverride None
                Options -Indexes -MultiViews -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location /wiki>
        </Location>

        <DirectoryMatch "^/home/www/wiki/html/(data|conf|bin|inc)/">
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
            Satisfy All
        </DirectoryMatch>

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        ErrorLog /home/www/wiki/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/www/wiki/logs/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

However now, when I browse to the IP address of the server, I get the contents of the /var/svn/repos directory, wheras when I just had the wiki page, I got the wiki index page. I can actually go to -IPaddress-/svn/repos and see the SVN repository, but -IPaddress-/wiki does not work.

Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your virtual hosts are on port 80 on the same machine. Apache can only guess which one you want to use. It is guessing the subversion one and browsing to the DocumentRoot specified. 
You need to differentiate the virtual hosts, or browse to the server using the server name rather than IP.

Instead you could setup the SVN location inside your other virtual host.

Also consider using /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf depending on your Operating System.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Adding it inside the other virtual host worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

> However now, when I browse to the IP address of the server, I get the contents of the /var/svn/repos directory, wheras when I just had the wiki page, I got the wiki index page. I can actually go to -IPaddress-/svn/repos and see the SVN repository, but -IPaddress-/wiki does not work.

When you make a request to apache and the hostname you are using isn't defined by any `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` in any of the vhosts, apache returns the ***default*** vhost, which is always the first vhost in the file (or in the file with the name that's the smallest lexiconical order, e.g. `00-default_vhosts.conf`). In your case, your SVN vhost is first so it is the "default" vhost. If you swap the 2 around the other one would be the "default" vhost.